# Inline if expected }

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Just trying to add inline if in my partial view but keep getting expecting }

Every 5 items I want in their own table

```
@model IList<PAL.Intranet.Models.MonitorDetailModel>

<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                @if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    <tr>
                }

                <td><img src="@if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.OK)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Alert)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Alert }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Warning)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Warning }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Critical)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Error)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Unknown)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Unknown }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Online)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Offline)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error }"                                
                          width="24" height="24"/></td>
                <td><b>@Model[i].Item:</b></td>
                <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">@Model[i].TaskItem.ToString():&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@if (@Model[i].Output != null)
                    { @Model[i].Output }
                    else
                    { @Model[i].AlertState.ToString() }</td>
                <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">Captured:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@Model[i].Captured</td>

                @if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    </td>
                }

            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

***Update 1***

Still getting expecting }. Every 5 items I want in there own table.

```
@model IList<PAL.Intranet.Models.MonitorDetailModel>
<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @if (i == 0 | i % 5 == 0)
        {
            <table>
            <tr>
        }
            <td><img src="@if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.OK)
                            { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK }
                            else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Alert)
                            { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Alert }
                            else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Warning)
                            { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Warning }
                            else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Critical)
                            { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error }
                            else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Error)
                            { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error }
                            else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Unknown)
                            { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Unknown }
                            else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Online)
                            { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK }
                            else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Offline)
                            { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error }"                                
                        width="24" height="24"/></td>
            <td><b>@Model[i].Item:</b></td>
            <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">@Model[i].TaskItem.ToString():&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>@if (@Model[i].Output != null)
                { @Model[i].Output }
                else
                { @Model[i].AlertState.ToString() }</td>
            <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">Captured:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>@Model[i].Captured</td>

            @if (i == 0 | i % 5 == 0)
            {
                </tr>
                </table>
            }
    }
</div>
```

***Update 3***

Expecting } at line 1, 1, 3, 39, 39

```
@model IList<PAL.Intranet.Models.MonitorDetailModel>
<div>       
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@Model[i].Output))
        {
            Model[i].Output = @Model[i].AlertState.ToString();
        }

        string image = string.Empty;
        switch (@Model[i].AlertState)
        {
            case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.OK:
                image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK;
                break;
            case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Warning:
                image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Warning;
                break;
            case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Critical:
                image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error;
                break;
            case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Error:
                image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error;
                break;
            case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Unknown:
                image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Unknown;
                break;
            case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Online:
                image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK;
                break;
            case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Offline:
                image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error;
                break;
            default:
                image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Unknown;
                break;
        }

        @if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            <table>           
        }
        <tr>
        <td><img src="@image" width="24" height="24"/></td>
        <td><b>@Model[i].Item:</b></td>
        <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">@Model[i].TaskItem.ToString():&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>@Model[i].Output</td>
        </tr>
        @if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            </table>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a better way? Still learning MVC but want to make it easy to edit so someone can just change the chtml file instead of loading up VS to change any other code.

Comment: @JAT yes every 5 items in the collection I want in their own table so I can display the tables side by side.

Comment: are you sure that your not just missing a `}` from a codeblock elsewhere that triggers it?

Comment: @maam27 yes this issue is only from the partial view.

Comment: If I remove the <table> and </table> from in the if statements the issue goes away but then I don't have my tables lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" with your code it's that Razor tries to find the closing tag of the table element, and because you actually never close it with good syntax, it's showing you are missing the closing bracket in the for loop and the table tag. As you said if you remove the table tag works great, then to avoid razor trying to complete the tag elements because the "error" tells you that it's because you don't have a closing tag just add a `@:` before the `<table>` and `</table>` and the problem should go away.

Of course you need to be sure your html code is fine, because you are telling razor that it's a string, not a table, but in HTML it will render as a `<table>` tag

```
 @model IList<PAL.Intranet.Models.MonitorDetailModel>
    <div>       
        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@Model[i].Output))
            {
                Model[i].Output = @Model[i].AlertState.ToString();
            }

            string image = string.Empty;
            switch (@Model[i].AlertState)
            {
                case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.OK:
                    image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK;
                    break;
                case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Warning:
                    image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Warning;
                    break;
                case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Critical:
                    image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error;
                    break;
                case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Error:
                    image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error;
                    break;
                case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Unknown:
                    image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Unknown;
                    break;
                case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Online:
                    image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK;
                    break;
                case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Offline:
                    image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error;
                    break;
                default:
                    image = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Unknown;
                    break;
            }

            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                @:<table>           
            }
            <tr>
            <td><img src="@image" width="24" height="24"/></td>
            <td><b>@Model[i].Item:</b></td>
            <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">@Model[i].TaskItem.ToString():&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>@Model[i].Output</td>
            </tr>
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                @:</table>
            }
        }
    </div>
```

I know it's a good solution but one of my friends did this once and that's how he solved that issue. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a td every 5th item, but in the if column you are triyng to initialise a tr and at the end trying to close a td.  There is a tag mismatch as per the posted code. Can you try the below code?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                @if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    <td>
                }

                <td><img src="@if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.OK)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Alert)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Alert }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Warning)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Warning }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Critical)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Error)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Unknown)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Unknown }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Online)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK }
                              else if (@Model[i].AlertState == PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Offline)
                              { @PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Error }"                                
                          width="24" height="24"/></td>
                <td><b>@Model[i].Item:</b></td>
                <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">@Model[i].TaskItem.ToString():&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@if (@Model[i].Output != null)
                    { @Model[i].Output }
                    else
                    { @Model[i].AlertState.ToString() }</td>
                <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">Captured:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@Model[i].Captured</td>

                @if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    </td>
                }

            </tr>
        </table>
    }
```

Comment: Oops but it's still giving me an error expecting } and complains the lower </td> has no starting tag but I assume that's normal since the starting tag is in another if statement

Comment: If I remove the <table> and </table> from in the if statements the issue goes away but now I don't have my tables lol

Comment: Why not put both the td in the same if statement? Because anyhow you are just trying to create a td for every 5th item if i am not wrong. With the current format it will wrap all your td's inside another td for every 5th item.

Comment: the first 5 items will be in table 1 each item will have 4 columns so there will be 5 rows. The next five I want in a table to the right of that displaying the same ..etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use razor block in combination with switch case.

```
@{
    string imageSource = string.Empty;
    switch (Model[i].AlertState) { 
        case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.OK:
            imageSource = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK ;
            break;
        case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Alert:
            imageSource = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Alert
            break;
        ...
    }
}

<td><img src="@imageSource" width="24" height="24"/></td>
```

**EDIT**

Use

```
@model IList<PAL.Intranet.Models.MonitorDetailModel>
<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        string imageSource = string.Empty;
        switch (Model[i].AlertState) { 
            case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.OK:
                imageSource = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.OK ;
                break;
            case PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertState.Alert:
                imageSource = PAL.Intranet.Models.AlertStateImage.Alert
                break;
            ...
        }

        @if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            <table>           
        }
        <tr>
            <td><img src="@imageSource" width="24" height="24"/></td>
            <td><b>@Model[i].Item:</b></td>
            <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">@Model[i].TaskItem.ToString():&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>@(Model[i].Output != null ? @Model[i].Output :@Model[i].AlertState.ToString())</td>
            <td>@Model[i].Captured</td>
        </tr>

        @if (i % 5 == 0)
        {             
            </table>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Doh I don't know why I didn't think of this. Looks a lot cleaner.
Still getting expecting }. Updated code